# Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I've copied over all the code including dependencies from the Resize Image Firebase Functions Extension. I'm running this in the Firebase Emulator and need to tweak it to serve my needs. However, for now, I have it set up almost exactly as the source code from the extension.

Ext URL: https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images

**My Local Setup:**
node: v14.17.5
npm: 7.23.0
firebase: 9.20.0

firebase-admin: ^9.11.1
firebase-functions": ^3.15.6
mkdirp: ^1.0.4
uuid: ^8.3.2

**Deps on the Extension**
firebase-admin: ^8.0.0
firebase-functions: ^3.13.2
mkdirp: ^1.0.4
sharp: 0.23.4
uuidv4: ^6.1.0

**Here's the code for resizing the image**
Please note the line: `await remoteFile.download({ destination: originalFile }); // <- Offending line of code...` as that is the line where it's failing.

```
const resizeImage = async (object): Promise<ResizedImageResult[]> => {
  logs.start();
  const { contentType } = object; // This is the image MIME type

  const tmpFilePath = path.resolve('/', path.dirname(object.name)); // Absolute path to dirname

  if (!contentType) {
    logs.noContentType();
    return;
  }

  if (!contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
    logs.contentTypeInvalid(contentType);
    return;
  }

  if (object.contentEncoding === 'gzip') {
    logs.gzipContentEncoding();
    return;
  }

  if (!supportedContentTypes.includes(contentType)) {
    logs.unsupportedType(supportedContentTypes, contentType);
    return;
  }

  if (config.includePathList && !startsWithArray(config.includePathList, tmpFilePath)) {
    logs.imageOutsideOfPaths(config.includePathList, tmpFilePath);
    return;
  }

  if (config.excludePathList && startsWithArray(config.excludePathList, tmpFilePath)) {
    logs.imageInsideOfExcludedPaths(config.excludePathList, tmpFilePath);
    return;
  }

  if (object.metadata && object.metadata.resizedImage === 'true') {
    logs.imageAlreadyResized();
    return;
  }

  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
  const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
  const fileDir = path.dirname(filePath);
  const fileExtension = path.extname(filePath);
  const fileNameWithoutExtension = extractFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath, fileExtension);
  const objectMetadata = object;

  let originalFile;
  let remoteFile: File;
  try {
    originalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
    const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(originalFile);

    // Create the temp directory where the storage file will be downloaded.
    logs.tempDirectoryCreating(tempLocalDir);
    await mkdirp(tempLocalDir);
    logs.tempDirectoryCreated(tempLocalDir);

    // Download file from bucket.
    remoteFile = bucket.file(filePath);
    logs.imageDownloading(filePath);
    logs.imageDownloading(originalFile);
    await remoteFile.download({ destination: originalFile }); // <- Offending line of code...
    logs.imageDownloaded(filePath, originalFile);

    // Get a unique list of image types
    const imageTypes = new Set(config.imageTypes);

    // Convert to a set to remove any duplicate sizes
    const imageSizes = new Set(config.imageSizes);

    const tasks: Promise<ResizedImageResult>[] = [];

    imageTypes.forEach((format) => {
      imageSizes.forEach((size) => {
        tasks.push(
          modifyImage({
            bucket,
            originalFile,
            fileDir,
            fileNameWithoutExtension,
            fileExtension,
            contentType,
            size,
            objectMetadata: objectMetadata,
            format,
          }),
        );
      });
    });

    const results = await Promise.all(tasks);

    const failed = results.some((result) => result.success === false);
    if (failed) {
      logs.failed();
      return;
    } else {
      if (config.deleteOriginalFile === deleteImage.onSuccess) {
        if (remoteFile) {
          try {
            logs.remoteFileDeleting(filePath);
            await remoteFile.delete();
            logs.remoteFileDeleted(filePath);
          } catch (err) {
            logs.info('Catch 1');
            logs.errorDeleting(err);
          }
        }
      }
      logs.complete();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    logs.info('Catch 2');
    logs.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (originalFile) {
      logs.tempOriginalFileDeleting(filePath);
      fs.unlinkSync(originalFile);
      logs.tempOriginalFileDeleted(filePath);
    }
    if (config.deleteOriginalFile === deleteImage.always) {
      // Delete the original file
      if (remoteFile) {
        try {
          logs.remoteFileDeleting(filePath);
          await remoteFile.delete();
          logs.remoteFileDeleted(filePath);
        } catch (err) {
          logs.errorDeleting(err);
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**Expected Behavior**

When executing `await remoteFile.download({ destination: originalFile });` it should download the original file. This code is exactly the same as the extension code.

**Actual Behavior**

The following error is logged out:

```
{
  "severity":"ERROR","message":"Error when resizing image TypeError: Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported
    at getNodeRequestOptions (.../node_modules/teeny-request/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1309:9)
    at .../node_modules/teeny-request/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1410:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Function.fetch [as default] (.../node_modules/teeny-request/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1407:9)
    at teenyRequest (.../node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:184:29)
    at Object.request (.../node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:241:20)
    at Timeout.makeRequest [as _onTimeout] (.../node_modules/retry-request/index.js:139:28)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)"
}
```

Anyone come across this issue? I can't go back to an earlier version of Firebase because there are breaking changes.

Comment: [Remember](/help/how-to-ask) to title your post with a concise summary of what you're asking about.

Comment: I created a test case. The error is different but it breaks at the same place:
https://github.com/vdiaz1130/fb-resize-image-locally Be sure to add your project to the .firebaserc file.

Comment: I tested this with my colleague and the code you posted on GitHub appears to be working well when deployed. Here's the [logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOEXk.png). Check your setup again and make sure that your dependencies matches with the one stated in your question.

Comment: @RobertG Thank you for testing. Yes, I am aware that it works when deployed. I was hoping to get this working locally in the emulator as there are changes I need to make to suit my needs. There's no need to use the matching dep 1. because it works when deployed and 2. because there are breaking changes in Firebase v8 vs v9 and I'm using v9.

Comment: Since this is an issue within the emulator after you upgraded, I would suggest to submit your issue through the [Firebase Tools Issue link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues).

Comment: For anyone else running into this issue, I fixed it by setting validation to false in the following line: await remoteFile.download({ destination: originalFile, validation: false }); 

I'll add logic to turn this on when not using the emulator.

Comment: @vdiaz1130 please post your solution as an answer. That way other people can upvote it if they find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else running into this issue, I fixed it by setting validation to false in the following line:
`await remoteFile.download({ destination: originalFile, validation: false });`

I'll add logic to turn validation on when not using the emulator. Also, make sure all the environment variables for the extension have default values (see the config.ts file in the extension's source code and see the VARIABLES tab in the Function Details page in GCP).